# Linq query parent child grouping issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following tables

```
Actions    
  ActionID   Action  NextActionID

    1        Submit      2
    2        Forward     3
    3        Approve    NULL

UserActionRights
UserID ActionID
  5     1
  6     2
  7     3
  8     2
```

I want output like this

```
Action(Key) UserIDs(List)
  1          6
             7

  2          7
  3         "Empty List"
```

What I have tried so for is as follows

```
(from a in actions join uar in UserActionRights on a.NextActionID equals uar.ActionID
Select new 
{
  Action=a.ActionID,
  UserIDs=uar.UserID

}).ToList().AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ActionID).Select(y => new 
                       {
                               Action = y.Key,
                               UserIDs = y.Select(tp=>tp.UserID)
}).ToList()
```

Now when user with ID=5 logged in I get empty output as it doesn't have the right for ActionID=2,3. I need to modify the query to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

It took some thinking to infer that you need a list of users privileged to do the actions subsequent to the key action:

```
UserActionRights.Select(u => new
    { ActionId = u.ActionId,
      UserIds = UserActionRights.Where(u1 => u1.ActionId > u.ActionId)
        .Select(u1 => u1.UserId).ToList()
    });
```

I hope I understood you well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Users.GroupBy(u => u.Action.Id, u => u.Id)
```